# MatPlotLib : Changing tick intervals when x axis values are dates

Tags: python

I want to display data from a data frame where the index are dates. I want to have a tick per month.
I want the ticks to be : 
-jan.
-feb.
...
-nov.
-dec.

By default the ticks are :
- jan.
-march
-may
... 
(does'nt display every month)

I have imposed a month format for the ticks and a 45 degrees rotation. I have try :

```py
ax1.locator_params(nbins=12, axis='x')
```

That is supposed to make 12 ticks but noting is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
```

Try this